# Doing an Ajax call based on results of first call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am making an AJAX call to refresh a view based on results I get after calling a controller action.

What I would like to do is use the results (`payrollResults`) to make a second AJAX call, to refresh a second partial.

Can I write a callback function, and then call it call it from inside the success function of the initial AJAX call (at the very end, to make sure it's done processing, before the second Ajax call is done)?

```
function returnPayrollData(payrollData){
    .ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/payroll/employees/" + employeeId,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "employee_payroll_data": payrollData
        }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        remote: false,
        success: function(payrollResults) {
          // refresh first partial here
        }
    })
}
```

I am using Rails 5.2 and jQuery 3

## Additional:

When I added:

```
alert('This is working')
```

I did get the alert, however if I have something like:

```
console.log("let's see if this works")
```

Then I don't see that in the console

Comment: yeah, what is your error ? you can call the second function and pass payrollResults as value

Comment: `I would like to use the results to make a second AJAX call, to refresh a second partial.` Don't do this. You're making additional unnecessary requests. Modify your server side logic to return all necessary information from a single request

Comment: Rails does not allow me to do two separate renders from a single controller method

Comment: The error is that I tried it, but nothing happens. I even tried to have the callback function output to the console, the results, but nothing happens

Comment: Can you please also put some server-side code as I think it is not responding with proper data otherwise the code should give output in the console.

Comment: Please see the edit to my question